# How to get data about Firebase's push notification conversion by it's id

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending data-only-payloaded message to `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` and receiving it's ID:

```
{"message_id":6399566057759755347}
```

After that I can't find this message in my firebase console notifications list but I need to get data about number of receivers and openers of notification and display it on my service (need to get data about conversion by API). Is there the way to implement it? If no - is logging of delivering and opening of notificaions on my own server is a good idea?